# How to sum similar element of an array of structure in vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an array of structures:

```
Public Structure emp
    Public empName As String
    Public empAge As Int32
    Public empsal As Int32 ' salary
End Structure
```

An array of the above structure with 30 element. I want to sum the `empsal` of those emp elements whose `emp.empName` & `emp.empAge` is equal.

for ex.

```
emp(0).empName = "test"
emp(0).empAge = 32
emp(0).empsal = 10000

emp(1).empName = "test"
emp(1).empAge = 32
emp(1).empsal = 10000

emp(2).empName = "test12"
emp(2).empAge = 32
emp(2).empsal = 10000
```

How can this be done so that the result will be **(test,20000) and (test12,10000)**?

Using .NET 3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Edited the samples to include the age in the key, and to end up with an `emp` array.

Absolutely. You should look at LINQ for this - you basically want to *group* by name and age, and then *sum* the salary. In C# you'd write something like:

```
var query = employees.GroupBy
     (x => new { x.empName, x.empAge },
      x => x.empSal,
      (key, salaries) => new emp { empName = key.empName,
                                   empAge = key.empAge,
                                   empSalary = salaries.Sum() })
var array = query.ToArray();
```

I *think* in VB this would be something like:

```
Dim query = employees.GroupBy( _
    Function(x) New With { Key .Name = x.empName, Key .Age = x.empAge }, _
    Function(x) x.empSal, _
    Function(k, salaries) New Emp With _
         { .empName = k.Name, .empAge = k.Age, .empSalary = salaries.Sum() }_
    )
Dim array = query.ToArray()
```

See the [`GroupBy` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534493.aspx#Y0) for more details.

As an aside, I would recommend:

- Giving your type a fuller name which follows .NET naming conventions
- Making it a class rather than a structure (it's not really a single value, like an `int`)
- Using properties instead of public fields
- Removing the `emp` prefix from the fields/properties - they're already part of an employee type, after all

Comment: `Function(name, salaries)` what it does?

Comment: I want store these `(test,20000) and (test12,10000)` values in a new array of type emp. How to achieve this.

Comment: I think you miss this point :- **An array of the above structure with 30 element. I want to sum the empsal of those emp elements whose emp.empName & emp.empAge is equal.**

Comment: @RittwickBanerjee: Well you didn't make it clear that you wanted to take age into account - given that you didn't include the age in the results. You also didn't make the result type clear at all. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for a guide to how to ask clear questions. Basically you can still use LINQ, but I suggest you read up more on it to start with. It looks like you'll want to group by name and age instead of just by name, but still sum the salary.

Comment: I think you didn't read my question at all. It clearly states that I want sum based on name & age. Please have a look at the example.

Comment: @RittwickBanerjee: I apologise, I did miss that - but you've got to admit that you *haven't* made it clear that you wanted to end up with an `emp` array. You just gave the result as "(test,20000) and (test12,10000)" - how were we meant to know what that is? Yes, I missed a small portion of the question - but the idea that I "didn't read [the] question at all" is pretty silly. How could I have written *any* answer without reading the question at all.

Comment: @RittwickBanerjee: Edited my answer with what I *think* the VB should be. The C# should be correct, but I'm not sure about the VB. I still suggest you pay attention to the final bullet points though.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping by name and age you could do something like the following in C#:

```
var query= from e in employees
  group e by new {e.empName, e.empAge} into g
  select new {Name=g.Key, Value=g.Sum(x=> x.empSal)};
```

In VB (per a converter):

```
Dim query= From g In From e In employeesGroup e By New From { _
    e.empName, _
    e.empAge _
}New With { _
    Key .Name = g.Key, _
    Key .Value = g.Sum(Function(x) x.empSal) _
}
```