# Iterate through Cart GroupBy and Sum

Tags: arrays, vb.net, linq, ienumerable

I need to iterate through a shopping cart, group by a code and date, then sum the integers that match the same code and date. Not sure if LINQ would help here. If its easier to avoid LINQ thats great to.

Here is my Class:

```
Class CartProduct

  Property ActCode As String
  Property Customers As Integer
  Property Date As Date 

End Class
```

Here is my Function:

```
Function GetTotals() As IEnumerable(Of String)

Dim totalList As New List(Of String)

   For Each p As CartProduct In _products

     totalList.Add(p.ActCode)
     totalList.Add(p.Customers)
     totalList.Add(p.Date)       

   Next

   Dim result = From newList In totalList
                Group by totalList.ActCode and totalList.Date
                Sum totalList.Customers ??? 
                Select newList {}

   Return result

End Function
```

Here is what _products returns:

```
 Friend Property Products As List(Of CartProduct)
    Get
        Return _products
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of CartProduct))
        _products = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I can't access the CartProduct properties to do the group by as its in a new list. This is what has me tripped up.

EDIT: Hopefully this leads me and others in a productive direction. 
[How to sum similar element of an array of structure in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241369/how-to-sum-similar-element-of-an-array-of-structure-in-vb-net)

Thanks.

Comment: How are you adding `Date` and `Integer` to a `List(Of String)` ? Does this code compile? What is the type of `_products`?

Comment: if i just wanted to return totalList, it compiles just fine. The cart has products with a string, date and integer. Multiple products could have different strings, dates and integers.

Comment: When I try I get you can't use `Date` as a property name, but I forgot VB probably auto-converts the other types to `string`. In this case, that isn't helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have edited my original post to include what _products actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group by and sum fields in `CartProduct`, then you just need to work with the `CartProduct` list directly:

```
Function GetTotals() As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim result = From p In _products
                 Group By p.ActCode, p.Date Into Sum(p.Customers)

   Return result
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you @NetMage. I knew it was something dumb i wasn't thinking about. I didn't know that i didn't need to use a For Each to iterate through the CartProducts.